# How to slice groups to nearest nth observation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a time series dataset that looks something like this:

```
Time   ID   X_Pos   Y_Pos
1      1    150     300
2      1    160     310
3      1    156     500
4      2    300     439 
5      2    200     500
6      3    500     320
7      3    400     230
8      3    500     540
9      3    450     600
10     3    400     600
```

I need to essentially round the number of observations within each ID to the nearest nth multiple, in this example, I will use the nearest 2. This should result in a dataset that looks like this:

```
Time   ID   X_Pos   Y_Pos
1      1    150     300
2      1    160     310
4      2    300     439 
5      2    200     500
6      3    500     320
7      3    400     230
8      3    500     540
9      3    450     600
```

As you can see, the exact number of rows remaining in each group differs depending on the initial size of the group, but always remains a multiple of 2.

I've gotten pretty close to getting what I need with the code below, but am missing the final step (noted by the question marks):

```
grouped = data.groupby('ID')
timesteps = 2

def round_down(num, divisor):
    return num - (num%divisor)

endSlice = pd.DataFrame(round_down(grouped.size(), timesteps)).reset_index()

slicedData = data.groupby('ID', as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0: ???????])
```

**EDIT**  The question is, what do I need to put in the portion of the code where the question marks are in order to achieve the desired dataset (i.e., the second dataset), OR, is there a more efficient way to achieve this dataset?

I think that the portion of the code where the question marks are just needs to refer to the endSlice value for each ID, but I'm pretty new to python and an lacking some knowledge on things like this.

Thanks in advance for any help and apologies if this has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: I don't fully understand what's your question?

Comment: I've added an edit to make the question more explicit.

Comment: What's `id_con`?

Comment: My mistake, that was left over from actual code, I've edited to make it consistent within the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this:

```
# Set the multiple that you want the size of each group to be:
n = 2

# Groupby ID, then apply .head() to get the size you want:
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.head(len(x) - len(x) % n)).reset_index(drop=True)

   Time  ID  X_Pos  Y_Pos
0     1   1    150    300
1     2   1    160    310
2     4   2    300    439
3     5   2    200    500
4     6   3    500    320
5     7   3    400    230
6     8   3    500    540
7     9   3    450    600
```

Note that this is essentially equivalent to your attempt with `iloc`, and there is no need for the `round_down` function:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:len(x)-len(x)%n]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Both of those will take the beginning of the data of each group, up to the nearest multiple of `n`.

If instead, you want *random data* (instead of the beginning of the data) for each group, but for the size of each group to still be a multiple of `n`, use `sample` instead of `head`/`iloc`:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.sample(len(x) - len(x) % n)).reset_index(drop=True)

   Time  ID  X_Pos  Y_Pos
0     2   1    160    310
1     1   1    150    300
2     4   2    300    439
3     5   2    200    500
4     9   3    450    600
5    10   3    400    600
6     8   3    500    540
7     6   3    500    320
```